# How do I retrieve all the data in my redis instance?

Tags: python, redis

I have a Redis instance with around 65k records. I want to retrieve them all at once. Here is what I have so far but it only gets one record at a time.
My data values are stored as JSON strings.

```
import redis
import json

r = redis.Redis(
    host=host,
    port=port, 
    password=password)

for key in r.scan_iter('*'):
    print(r.get(key))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using mget.

```
values = r.mget(r.keys())
```

I realize r.keys() can cause issues. For my needs it's fine.

If you decide to use this solution be aware of that.